# How can I identify which process is using port 18780 on Windows?

Tags: windows, port

I have an internal web application listening on all IPs on port 18780. When I try to start the application on a new Windows VM it throws this exception:

`System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:18780`

After rebooting the machine the application starts just fine, but I'd like to avoid having to reboot all of my new QA environments before I can use them.

[IANA reports that nothing well-known uses port 18780.](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=18780)

The last time this happened I tried to identify what process was running on that port:

[image: Powershell window displaying output from Get-NetTCPConnection]

Running `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 18780).OwningProcess` returned `Cannot find a process with the process identifier 7188`. Powershell is running under a local admin account.

So what's happening here? It looks like there's something using that port, it's got a process Id, but I'm unable to get the details of it. Running this powershell command a second time reports that there's nothing listening that port. Does the act of observation change Windows processes?

What further steps can I take to find out more about Schrödinger's process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caught this happening again.

Turns out that my application had spawned three child processes, and those were still running. Windows apparently doesn't release a TCP port until the owning process *record* is cleaned up, and child processes maintain this record. Even though the parent process was stopped, and showed in TCPViewer as `<non-existent>`, the port was still unavailable.

This is also described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/181015/how-do-you-free-up-a-port-being-held-open-by-dead-process

I used `wmic process where (ParentProcessId=7188) get Caption,ProcessId` to identify which child processes to kill, and that did the trick. Windows released the port straight away.

Answer (score 0):

try following in powershell:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<port>
```

this will give you the details about the process id

then use following to kill the process:

```
taskkill /PID <processid> /F
```